# How to convert Java lambda based on functional interface to Kotlin one?

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming

I have the next java functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FragmentHandler {
     void onFragment(DirectBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Header header);
}
```

I have a very simple interface implementation

```
public static FragmentHandler printStringMessage(int streamId) {
    return (buffer, offset, length, header) -> {
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        buffer.getBytes(offset, data);
        System.out.println(String.format("Message to stream %d from session %d (%d@%d) <<%s>>", streamId, header.sessionId(), length, offset, new String(data)));
    };
}
```

I'd like to write the same structure using Kotlin

```
fun printStringMessage(streamId: Int): FragmentHandler {
    val lambda: (DirectBuffer, Int, Int, Header) -> Unit = { buffer: DirectBuffer, length: Int, offset: Int, header: Header ->
        val data = ByteArray(length)
        buffer.getBytes(offset, data)
        println(String.format("Message to stream %d from session %d (%d@%d) <<%s>>", streamId, header.sessionId(), length, offset, String(data)))
    }
}
```

But this code is not valid. I don't undersrand how to implement the same peace of logic in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SAM constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to specify the interface you want your lambda to represent, like this:

```
fun printStringMessage(streamId: Int): FragmentHandler {
    val fragmentHandler = FragmentHandler { buffer: DirectBuffer, length: Int, offset: Int, header: Header ->
        val data = ByteArray(length)
        buffer.getBytes(offset, data)
        println(String.format("Message to stream %d from session %d (%d@%d) <<%s>>", streamId, header.sessionId(), length, offset, String(data)))
    }
    return fragmentHandler
}
```

This would also allow you to leave off the explicit types from the parameters, if you wanted to, plus you can of course return the instance directly:

```
fun printStringMessage(streamId: Int): FragmentHandler {
    return FragmentHandler { buffer, length, offset, header ->
        val data = ByteArray(length)
        buffer.getBytes(offset, data)
        println(String.format("Message to stream %d from session %d (%d@%d) <<%s>>", streamId, header.sessionId(), length, offset, String(data)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer of your question:

```
fun printStringMessage(streamId: Int): FragmentHandler {
    val lambda = FragmentHandler { buffer: DirectBuffer, length: Int, offset: Int, header: Header ->
        val data = ByteArray(length)
        buffer.getBytes(offset, data)
        println(String.format("Message to stream %d from session %d (%d@%d) <<%s>>", streamId, header.sessionId(), length, offset, String(data)))
    }
return lambda
}
```